# Using dateutil. parser to account for timezones, but parse won't recognizer tzinfos?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, timezone, python-dateutil

I'm trying to extract time stamps from a list that contains different timezones.
I am using dateutil.parser. I believe I want to use the parse function for this, including timezone information, but it appears it doesn't want to accept them. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
timezone_info = {
    "PDT": "UTC -7",
    "PST": "UTC -8",
    }
date_list = ['Oct 21, 2019 19:30 PDT',
             'Nov 4, 2019 18:30 PST']

for dates in date_list:
    print(parse(dates))
# This gives:
# 2019-10-21 19:30:00
# 2019-11-04 18:30:00

for date in date_list:
    print(parse(dates, tzinfos = timezone_info))
```

This is the output:

```
2019-10-21 19:30:00
2019-11-04 18:30:00
C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py:1218: UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname PDT identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)
C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py:1218: UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname PST identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mbsta/PycharmProjects/untitled2/tester.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(parse(dates, tzinfos = timezone_info))
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1374, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 660, in parse
    ret = self._build_tzaware(ret, res, tzinfos)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1185, in _build_tzaware
    tzinfo = self._build_tzinfo(tzinfos, res.tzname, res.tzoffset)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1175, in _build_tzinfo
    tzinfo = tz.tzstr(tzdata)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\dateutil\tz\_factories.py", line 69, in __call__
    cls.instance(s, posix_offset))
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\dateutil\tz\_factories.py", line 22, in instance
    return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\dateutil\tz\tz.py", line 1087, in __init__
    raise ValueError("unknown string format")
ValueError: unknown string format

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue here is that the offsets you are specifying are not a valid format for `tzstr`, which expects something that looks like a [TZ variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html). If you change the strings to `"PST+8"` and `"PDT+7"`, respectively, it will work as intended.

That said, I think you'd be much better off using a `tzfile`, which is one of the main things that `tzinfos` is for:

```
from dateutil import parser
from dateutil import tz
PACIFIC = tz.gettz("America/Los_Angeles")
timezone_info = {"PST": PACIFIC, "PDT": PACIFIC}

date_list = ["Oct 21, 2019 19:30 PDT",
             "Nov 4, 2019 18:30 PST"]

for dtstr in date_list:
    print(parser.parse(dtstr, tzinfos=timezone_info))
```

This prints:

```
2019-10-21 19:30:00-07:00
2019-11-04 18:30:00-08:00
```

And since it attaches a full time zone offset, you can do arithmetic on the results without worrying (since it's a full time zone, not a fixed offset).

Comment: Thank you sir, much appreciated!
My date list will have a mix of all kinds of abbreviated timezones. will I need to create something like 'PACIFIC = tz.gettz("America/Los_Angeles") 'and ' "PST": PACIFIC' for each one that could appear?

Comment: Yes, three/four letter abbreviations are generally ambiguous. If you want to disambiguate between them, you need to provide the context. You can use a mapping like a dictionary or pass a function to tzinfos.